# How to correctly register an imported dynamic component when using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-dynamic-components

I have a Vue CLI 3 project that is attempting to dynamically load a component from within a watched property on a base component. Is it even possible to dynamically register an component locally like this at runtime?

I can import components dynamically as long as I register them in the `components` property first.

The base component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="component"></component>
    </div>
</template>
@Component<BaseComponent>({
  watch: {
    childComponentName(componentName) {
       Vue.component(componentName, import(/* webpackChunkName: 'child' */  `./${componentName}.vue`).then(m => m.default || m);
       this.component = componentName;
    }
})
export default class BaseComponent extends Vue {...}
```

and the child component is

```
@Component<child>({
  name: 'child',
})
export default class child extends Vue {...}
```

I understand the code above is doing global registration which needs to happen before the `App` component is created but is there a way to register it locally?

The component should register the child component based on the variable name and render it instead
Vue throws an error because the component is not registered:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <child> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <BaseComponent> at src/components/BaseComponent.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Comment: cant you just `this.component = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'child' */  \`./${componentName}.vue\`)`?

Comment: @Estradiaz apparently you can.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [@Estradiaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11204469/estradiaz) at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523471/how-to-correctly-register-an-imported-dynamic-component-when-using-typescript#comment97752054_55523471), you can pass the `Promise` to import the component directly into the `:is` directive:

```vue
this.component = () => import(`./${componentName}.vue`)
```